# WPF AutomationPeer not returning Bounding Rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, automated-tests, ui-automation

I've got two classes of thumb controls I'm working with:

- `AutomatedThumb`
- `TouchEnabledThumb`

The `TouchEnabledThumb` class is just that, and extension to the base WPF thumb class. `AutomatedThumb` is an experiment on my part.

I've had trouble getting the UI Automation Framework to interact with the controls. At first they were showing up in UI Automation Verify grayed out with no bounding box. I've written automation peer classes for the controls and given them both `OnCreateAutomationPeer` overrides, it's resulted in the controls no longer being grayed out in UIAV but none of the controls are returning a bounding rectangle so I can't move the mouse to them to interact.

I've been trying to override `GetBoundingRectangleCore` using `Owner.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(Owner.RenderSize))` but they don't ever return a bounding box to the automation tree.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I've tried having `GetBoundingRectanbleCore` return a `Rect` with values of `(1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0)` and the bounding box shows up like I want it to. I just need to figure out how to get the bounding rectangle for the actual controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there's a problem with the `GetBoundingRectangleCore` for `Thumb` controls and thus derived controls. The returned `Rect` object comes out with the upper left corner as expected but, it has a height and width of `0` which seems to make the automation tree freak and show no bounding box.

So the solution a co-worker and I came up with is as follows:

```
protected override GetBoundingRectangleCore()
{
    var result = base.GetBoundingRectangleCore();
    if(result.Width == 0 || result.Height == 0)
        return new Rect(result.TopLeft, new Point(result.Left + 1, result.Bottom + 1));

    return result;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else who is banging their head against this problem.